# Adding info window to google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having difficulty adding info windows to the markers on this google map. I have tried different methods but I think I am adding the code to the wrong place or calling the wrong variables. Can anyone help me out? thanks!

```
var beaches = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 2]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var markers = [];

var i, newMarker;

for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
        map: map,
        title: beaches[i][0]
    });

    newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];
    newMarker.setVisible(false);

    markers.push(newMarker);
}

function displayMarkers(category) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].category === category) {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', (function (markers, i) {
    return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, markers);
    }
})(markers, i));
```

Comment: Did you not find an example on this website?

Comment: Apologies, I have tried that page but I think I'm using the wrong variable names. I have updated the original post with my implementation of this example included. Cheers!

Comment: Is this your complete code? I will write an answer below but with the duplicate I posted above you should be able to get it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var markers = [];

function initialize() {

    var beaches = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 2]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {

        var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
            map: map,
            title: beaches[i][0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', (function (newMarker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
            }
        })(newMarker, i));

        markers.push(newMarker);
    }
}

initialize();
```

I have wrapped your code in an init function. Mind your variables declarations / scopes. If you have questions, let me know. You were not too far from it...

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/7TZFP/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks again! was there any reason why you removed the code that assigns the markers categories? Markers are in either group 1 or 2 and are hidden/shown using a checkbox in the html. EDIT, I put this back in and got it working. Finally getting the hang of this

Comment: Well I try to shorten code to the minimum for a working example...

Comment: Keep doing what your doing! thanks for your help again